# How to return related entities when inserting/posting a new one using OData Web Api

Tags: entity-framework, post, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created an OData v4 endpoint using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 and wondering how to return related entities when inserting/posting a new one?

**Controller:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(LibraryFolder libraryFolder)
{
    this.db.LibraryFolders.Add(libraryFolder);

    //Add MediaFiles to the conext 
    this.businessController.RefreshLibrary(libraryFolder);

    await this.db.SaveChangesAsync();

    //The libraryFolder object contains the MediaFiles at this point, but they get stripped out when going back to the client
    return this.Created(libraryFolder);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply to add [EnableQuery] on the `Post` action. For example:

```
[EnableQuery]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(LibraryFolder libraryFolder)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, send the Post request to the Uri with `$expand` clause. For example:

```
POST http://..../odata/LibraryFolders?$expand=XXXX
Content-Type: application/json
Content: {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sam-Xu! This totally worked! For anyone wanting to know how to get this to work with Microsoft.OData.Client library you simply hook into the BuildingRequest event and append the URL like Sam Xu said:

`private void Container_BuildingRequest(object sender, Microsoft.OData.Client.BuildingRequestEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Method == "POST" && e.RequestUri.Segments.Any(x => x == "LibraryFolders"))
        e.RequestUri = new Uri(e.RequestUri, "?$expand=MediaFiles");
}`